# ECS Task failed to start with no logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am trying to deploy a service on AWS ECS where task is failing to start and fails after 3-4 minutes. No logs are found for the failure. It just changes from PENDING -> STOPPED.

[image]

After few failures (PENDING -> STOPPED) on task like this, the service comes up after a few retry and it moves from PENDING -> RUNNING without any interruptions. I am trying to debug why it goes (PENDING -> STOPPED) many times before running correctly.

Docker images of the service is around ~10GB and service is deployed on GD4N.xlarge instance.

It looks like it is timing out while pulling the docker image of 10GB and stopping down. I have tried setting down ECS_CONTAINER_START_TIMEOUT but still it fails with same error under same timing failing in 3-4 minutes.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-config.html

```
            autoScalingGroup.addUserData(...[
                `echo ECS_CONTAINER_START_TIMEOUT=9m >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config`,  // increasing the start timeout for containers
                `echo ECS_CONTAINER_CREATE_TIMEOUT=9m >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config`,  // increasing the create timeout for containers
                `echo ECS_LOGLEVEL=debug >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config`,  // debug mode for ecs agent
                `echo ECS_IMAGE_PULL_BEHAVIOR=prefer-cached >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config`,  // debug mode for ecs agent
                `echo ECS_IMAGE_PULL_INACTIVITY_TIMEOUT=5m >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config`,  // debug mode for ecs agent
            ])
```

I am looking for direction on how it can debugged further?
And how i can increase the timeout from PENDING to RUNNING, so it does not stop.

Comment: What does the VPC setup look like, do all subnets have identical routing to access ECR to pull the image? E.g. do all working instances "coincidentally" deploy into the same subnet?

Comment: @luk2302 Yes, all subnets have identical routing to access ECR to pull the image. And currently i have only one instance running. 

Also we have permission as follows - ```
        asg.role.addManagedPolicy( 
            ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly')
        );``` . Also after a lot of failures, unpredictable it is able to pull the docker image and instance comes up running correctly.